# Can a drawable shape have it's size set to fill_parent?

Tags: android, android-drawable

Is it valid for a drawable shape in Android to use `fill_parent` for it's size?

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

<solid
        android:color="#666666"/>

<size
        android:width="fill_parent"
        android:height="fill_parent"/>
</shape>
```

**EDIT**

This for the background of `ImageButton` views. I want the icon for the button to have a circle behind it, but I don't always know what the size of the button will be (different sizes per layout).

Comment: If you want to fill the entire layout remove the size tag

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so - at this stage they are not attached to any view. Also according to the docs only dimension values are valid.

Comment: Thanks guys, I updated the question to clarify.

Comment: @blackbelt I don't want to fill the entire layout. Just the background of the button.

Comment: it is the same. Remove it and It will the entire available space

Comment: To be quite honest this is very disappointing, the android framework simply lack this. I've been scouring the net for countless hours and it is really not possible. Most stuff I see are hacks which complicates the code and the design. This is just me, the layouting feature here is very restrictive.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not really. Not using a `ShapeDrawable` alone. If you go through the `ShapeDrawable` document, you will see (*you are already using them in the  tag*) that the only valid attributes there are **px**, **dp**, **sp**, **in** and **mm**

A quote from the doc: [`android:width="...."`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html#attr_android:width)

> Available units are: px (pixels), dp (density-independent pixels), sp
>   (scaled pixels based on preferred font size), in (inches), mm
>   (millimeters)
>    This is true for the attribute: [`android:height`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html#attr_android:height)

*This is speculation on my part*, but I suspect why the fill_parent attribute value will not work is because a `ShapeDrawble`, unlike an `XML Layout` file will not have a parent container.

Leaving out the `<size.... />` attribute entirely and setting the `layout_width` and `layout_height` on a Widget that will reference the said ShapeDrawable is the only option I suspect (if the *`fill_parent`* is to be honored).

Comment: @VikrantAlekar: You will have to be more specific. I don't quite understand your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which API level this took effect, but per the Shape drawable documentation, it will be scaled proportionately to fit the view. So you can, for example, put width=1dp and height=1dp. See https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Answer (score 0):

How do you plan to use this shape? You can set it as src or background for any view and set view height in "fill_parent" - it's more usual way.

Comment: What if you want your shape to sit along the bottom of the parent view

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it from the xml file, but you can do it from the java file. Just use

`public final void resize (float width, float height)`

Comment: resize() on what object?