# Custom seekBar drawable XML: set thumb size to available height

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I want to have a seekBar and its thumb's height sized to a proportion of the screen. For example, their height to 10% of screen height, where the seekBar's container's height is set to 10% of screen height, and seekBar's height is set to 'match_parent'.

I have adapted [this tutorial](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/androids-seekbar-your-way/). So I created a file 'thumb_drawable.xml' in 'res/XML':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <gradient android:startColor="#ffffffff" android:endColor="#ff585858" android:angle="270"/>
    <size android:height="20dp" android:width="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

and in my layout file, have this:

```
<SeekBar
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:thumb="@xml/thumb_drawable"
```

What is the simplest way of changing this so the thumb resizes to match the seekBar's size? Preferably all through the XML rather than Java. Previous questions don't cut it, maybe I'm being stupid:

- [How do I get the thumb of an Android SeekBar to match the height of the SeekBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648311/how-do-i-get-the-thumb-of-an-android-seekbar-to-match-the-height-of-the-seekbar) - This does not implement it in XML
- [Can a drawable shape have it's size set to fill_parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17111393/can-a-drawable-shape-have-its-size-set-to-fill-parent) - Leaving out the size attribute results in the thumb not being visible at all.

Thanks